# Use Visual Studio 2010 build in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution created with Visual Studio 2010 that uses an old version of Component One.  Component One needs a license.  The solution works well with Visual Studio 2010, but it displays a license error with Visual Studio 2015. The file `[projectName].exe.licenses` is not generated.

I would like to use the build of Visual Studio 2010 in Visual Studio 2015. I have already checked my debug source file in the solution properties/debug sources files as Visual Studio 2010 (i.e Visual Studio 10.0).

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have Visual Studio 2010 installed and is the solution not opening correctly in that, or are you asking if you can make Visual Studio 2015 emulate Visual Studio 2010 somehow, or use the old MSBuild version with the new interface? The answer to the latter is a definite "no".

Comment: I have both Visual Studio 2010 and 2015.

My solution compiles well with Visual Studio 2010, but it does not compiles with Visual Studio 2015.

I would like to Visual Studio 2015 emulate Visual Studio 2010 somehow (i.e. use Visual Studio 2010 compiler in Visual Studio 2015)